# Multiple IntentService calls vs single service with multiple parallel threads

Tags: android, multithreading, image, bitmap, filesystems

I have two operations that I need to perform on 400 large image files. The files are being downloaded over a private network to folderA.

- Operation 1: move the files from folderA to folderB
- Operation 2: resize each file

The thing is I have a small time window for moving the files from folderA to folderB, in fact as soon as a photo hits folderA it needs to be in folderB. What is my best approach for doing this? Right now I am considering two avenues.

Approach 1 (what I have now, too slow):

- Use a FileObserver to track when photos are in folderA
- Use an IntentService to: get image from folderA, resize image, then save new image to folderB

Approach 2 (wondering):

- Use a FileObserver to track when photos are in folderA
- Use a service with a custom Handler that allows parallel threads and for each photo, create a new thread to do: get image from folderA, resize image, then save new image to folderB

Approach 3:

- Use a FileObserver to track when photos are in folderA
- Use an IntentService to: for-each file, first move the file from folderA to folderB; then start another IntentService to resize the file.

I already know that approach 1 is not fast enough as it is the one I am now using. So, between approach 2 and 3, which one is faster and why? For example we are talking about 400 large image files. Does the OS impose limits on how many concurrent threads a single service can have? Should I worry about increasing thread pool? How about in case 3 where I am using two services (MoveIntentService and ResizeIntentService), how do I tell android to run “all” the calls to MoveService before the calls to ResizeService?

I understand that ResizeIntentService queues all the calls. But I am okay with that. I just need for MoveIntentService to move the files very very very quickly.

Also, although I say 400 files, I don't really know how many files and so I cannot wait for folderB to be full before I start the resize portion. I am also aware of the case where I can use a single IntentService to first move a file and then start a thread to resize the file.

Again, is it cheap to move a file in android (i.e. pointer versus actual re-copy)? I am here assuming that it is very cheap to move a file relative to resizing a file.

BTW both folderA and folderB are some level under `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Comment: You'll have to build a test project and try out what works best. I would go with the single service with a thread pool with a number of threads based on the number of CPU cores the device has, but unless you run some metrics with different approaches, you can't really tell what's best.